# Search for word in file, but not as part of another word

Tags: python

I have a text file with one word per line. Each word may actually be several words combined without a space, e.g. `thisisthexample`.

Right now, I have a test word that I check against the file:

`if test_word in open(FILENAME).read():`

If `test_word = "example"`, and `thisistheexample` is one of the lines in the file, the statement above will evaluate to `True`, correct?

Is there a way around this, to only return `True` if exactly `"example"` is in the file, and no other combination of `"example"` plus one or more characters? Would I do something like this below?

```
with open(FILENAME) as file:
    for line in file:
        if line == test_word
```

Thanks!

Comment: `if test_word in line.split():`

Comment: as there is one word per line use `readline()` medthod and then search using `in`

Comment: I think this should do it: `if test_word in {line.strip()}:`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
search_word = input("Enter word to search: ")
with open("FILENAME","r") as file:
    for word in file:
        if search_word == word.strip():
            print(search_word," found in file")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use re module and \b to check:

```
import re
a = 'If test_word = "example", and thisistheexample is one of the lines in the file, the statement above will evaluate to True, correct?'
regex = re.compile(r"\bexample\b")
result = regex.findall(a)
```

if the length of result is not zero, so the word is exists.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use readline method

```
with open("file.txt") as _fp:
    _words = _fp.readlines()
    for i in xrange(len(_words)):
        _words[i]=_words[i].strip()
    if 'search_word' in _words:
        print "Found"
```

This will work as multiple word combined without space in one line will be indexed in a `list` and you can use `in` to find the exact match, or `regex`

here is one example:

```
>>> a=["applearered","banana"]
>>> "apple" in a
False
>>> "banana" in a
True
```

Comment: This does not answer OPs question. He needs to look for exact word matches. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: I've added more proof that it might, please check once

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya please read the code carefully it will work

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee Ignoring the typo in your answer, please read the documentation of [readlines](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) which uses [readline](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readline.htm). It leaves the new line character in the string. The `in` matching won't match.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I think Soumesh uses `readlines` and not `readline`. Major difference here. But yes, the newline character and the typo has to be accounted for. However, this is ontrack to a proper solution.

Comment: @Tuan333 I mentioned `readline` because the `readlines` documentation says that it uses `readline` and that is where it is clarified that the new line character is left in the string. I have edited my comment to make it clear.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya As I said, I agreed that the newline character has to be accounted for, all I am saying is `readline` is very much different from `readlines`. Implementation details of these functions do not concern us here. I think Soumesh' idea is to get all lines into an array of string (1 string per line), and that's the right approach. I agree that the bug has to be accounted for, but I also agree with Soumesh that this is the approach OP can take.

Comment: @Tuan333 I am not saying that this can never be a right answer. I have downvoted because the answer is incorrect right now. If Soumesh fixes all the bugs, I will take back my down vote. About your comment, implementation details do not concern us, but the effects do! The `readlines` document doesn't say anything about the new line character and hence I had to link the readline. Anyway I have clarified that in my comment.

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee your code still is incorrect. I suggest running the code through an interpreter before posting.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Thank you for the clarification. I agree with you here.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya bug have been addressed, I didn't find any typos as of now

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee with the recent [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45931243/4) you have completely broken the logic. Even if we ignore the typo again, using `in` with a single word does not do exact word match.

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee there is still a typo. You use `word` and `_word`. Can you please run the code through an interpreter before posting?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya it work for me now please check